# semantic_form text clears on click from textbox in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, semantics, formtastic

I am using gem 'formtastic', '2.1'
my model:
employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :designation, :about
end
```

my view(edit.html.erb)

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin,@employee], :html => { :multipart => true, :class =>"form" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name, :hint => "should be less then or equal to 30 characters" %>
    <%= f.input :designation %>
    <%= f.input :about, :input_html => { :rows => 5 } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.buttons do |button| %>
    <button class="button" type="submit">
    </button>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now when i try to edit this page and click on the textbox, all the text is cleared.
But i want to just edit(append or make changes to data)
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was problem with my own javascript which was clearing text on blur.